# Bootstrap 3 panel disable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I using bootstrap v3 panel like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body"> 
         <input type="text" placeholder="your input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

live version: http://plnkr.co/edit/azAk6jqilJnozNK9SFMv

What I trying to do is to disable it for user editing (inputs, buttons, ...).

Tried two solutions: add disable attribute AND add "disabled" class. Not working.

Is this possible?

Comment: does "bla bla" contain form elements? That's specifically what you've asked how to disable (form elements). The "disable" attribute will work on a form. You can't "disable" a div.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [bootstrap docs section about disabled forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-disabled)?

Comment: Using `fieldset` is looks great! working for me.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever Sure wish you'd add an actual Answer and show us more detail about what your solution "looks like." :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding `disabled` attribute [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/vaeyxtdf/) and it worked well.

**Code**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your input" disabled/>
```